# Syntax to Sqoop import 5 out of 100 tables present in database - don't use exclude keyword?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I have 100 tables in a database. 
I want to import only 5 tables.
I can't/don't use "-- exclude" command

Comment: Write 5 import commands...

Comment: Sqoop allows you to bring one table at a time. Even bring data given a specific query. Could be better you can try something first and share what you have done so far.  Sqoop Selecting data you want to bring: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This can be done by shell script.

1)Prepare a input file which has list of 5 DBNAME.TABLENAME 
2)The shell script will have this file as input, iterate line by line and execute sqoop statement for each line.
while read line;
do

    DBNAME=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1` 
    tableName=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f2`


    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$RM_QUEUE_NAME --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --table $tableName  --target-dir $DATA_COLLECTOR/$tableName  --fields-terminated-by '\001'  -m 1 

done<inputFile
```