# How to dynamically import tables in Sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

In a MYSQL database we have 1000 tables.
I need to import 500 tables out of 1000 in to HDFS.
I have to do it in a single command.
Please help.

Comment: try this link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64361/how-to-implement-and-deploying-our-own-sqoop-frame.html

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469413/syntax-to-sqoop-import-5-out-of-100-tables-present-in-database-dont-use-exclu/50490943#50490943